# What happens to existing Pull Requests when the target branch is deleted?

Tags: git, github

Imagine a situation where you have 3 branches: `master`, `my_feature`, `my_feature_fix`.

Then the following actions are performed:

- A Pull-Request is opened to merge `my_feature_fix` into `my_feature`.
- In the meantime, `my_feature` is merged into `master` and the branch is deleted.

What happens to the open PR of `my_feature_fix` since `my_feature` no longer exists?

Comment: There will probably be a warning saying that the branch does not exist anymore. Why don't you try it out?

Comment: @FelixKling I planned on trying it out, but it seemed like a reasonable question to post for the Q&A format of this site. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Tried it out and here's what happens:

- If `my_feature` is merged into `master` and not deleted, the open PR of `my_feature_fix` into `my_feature` remains and can still be merged into the existing `my_feature` branch.
- While the `my_feature_fix` PR is open, the GitHub interface blocks you from deleting the `my_feature` branch: "You can't delete this branch because an open pull request depends on it."
- If the branch is forcibly deleted (`git branch -d my_feature`), the open PR of `my_feature_fix` is automatically closed and labeled as "Closed with unmerged commits."

Comment: Looks like this has changed, because now the GitHub interface does let you delete the branch, and closes any open pull requests which target the branch (without warning).  

Also note that "Closed with unmerged commits." is text which appears on the pull request page, not an issue label you can search for.

Comment: This has changed again.  Now open PRs targeting the deleted branch are automatically retargeted to the branch it was merged into, and "Base automatically changed from" shows up.